# Container's style to vertical align image inside

Tags: reactjs, styles, alignment, vertical-alignment

I want the image inside the container vertical align in center.
I tried below, all failed:

```
display:"inline-block", alignItems:"center", valign:"middle", verticalAlign:"middle",
```

My code is below:

```
<p style={{display:"inline-block", alignItems:"center", valign:"middle",
verticalAlign:"middle", textAlign:"center", width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>

<img style={{height: "auto", display:"inline-block", valign:"middle",
verticalAlign:"middle", width: "auto", maxWidth: "380px", maxHeight: "200px", 
overflow: "hidden" }}
src= "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/sign-check-icon.png" />

</p>
```

Answer (score 12):

You've to set `display: flex`.

```
const style = { display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', width: '..', height: '..'}

<p class="container" style={style}>
    <img src={} width={} height={} />
  </p>
```

Comment: @Todayboy - so what ended up being your style property to get vertical alignment to work? I'm struggling with it and can't figure it out based on this answer.